# Convolutional codes with specific free distance and constraint length

Tags: channelcoding

I have to implement a paper where the author in the simulation section has only mentioned the free distance and states(constraint length) of the convolutional code. I have searched the 3GPP documentation but could not find generator polynomials for the code. The author mentions a Rate 1/2 free distance 10 and 64 state convolutional code. Can anyone tell me how to search the generator polynomial for such a code.

Comment: Context! Why do you even care about 3gpp? There's incredibly many code families out there, we can't guess from the information you're giving what the right thing would be. But maybe someone who knows what the paper is about might – for example, there's not that many convolutional codes used by Standard XY in the versions that existed 1988 and could be discussed in a paper on turbo-decoding. But you don't tell us about the paper you're referring to. So, please add a link (or at least a proper citation) to that paper to your question, to make it answerable.

Comment: Please [**edit**](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/82719/edit) your question to include that central piece of information :)

Comment: Okay the paper I am referring to is "Link Resource Adaptation for Multiantenna
Bit-Interleaved Coded Multicarrier Systems".

Comment: ... please **edit** your question to include that central …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I was looking it for days. Now I have found the answer so I want to post it incase someone else also needs this . The answer is given in the paper
TCM, TTCM, BICM AND ITERATIVE BICM ASSISTED OFDM-BASED DIGITAL VIDEO BROADCASTING TO MOBILE RECEIVERS. Here they have mentioned such a generator polynomial which is [171,133]